# How to know the iteration in v-for

Tags: vue.js, iteration, checked, v-for

i'm in Vue.js
I made a radio input component, I use a v-for to display all the input and label, I would like to know if I can tell it to pass the checked attribute to the element from the first iteration of the v-for loop

```html
<div v-for="(option) in options" :key="option.name">
  <label class="form-check-label mr-2" :for="option.for">
    {{ option.name }}
  </label>
  <input
    v-model="selectedChoice" 
    class="mr-4" 
    type="radio" 
    name="radio" 
    :id="option.for" 
  />
</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand you correct you want to check your first `radio button` from your `v-for`.

You have two options to achieve that:

*First option* 
You can set `selectedChoice` to your first choice like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    options: ['yourChoice1', 'yourChoice2'] //you have to set your array in here
    selectedChoice: 'yourChoice1',
  }
}
```

*Second option* 
You set your data prop to the first item in your `array` - this is able because you're using `v-model` - you do it like this:

```
this.selectedChoice = this.yourChoice[0]
```

Hopefully this helps you out - please let me know!

Comment: no sorry, I probably misspoke, I just want to be able to add the checked attribute to my first option.

Comment: what do you mean with the ```add checked attribute to first option``` ? what should your output be?

Comment: like that :
 `<input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey" checked>`

but i want the "checked" only in the first input generate by the v-for

Comment: As I understand it here, I understood your question correct and you can see the answer above. In *first* or *second option* I answered that only the ```first``` generated ```input``` will be ```checked``` of ```v-for``` loop

Comment: hmm ok i think i understand, i ll try, thanks for your answer !